# Detecting End of Call with Broadcast Receiver inside a service

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I'm writing an Android app, I need to run a broadcast receiver inside a service, the receiver detects when there is an incoming call and when the call is ended or answered, the service puts the phone to silent mode and the receiver detects when there is an incoming call, if there is an incoming call, the receiver sets the ringer mode to ring and vibrate normally, when the call is answered or over, the receiver sets the ringer to silent mode again.

here is my receiver:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver CallReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        AudioManager amanager=(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        amanager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(state))
        {
            amanager.setRingerMode(2);  //Ringer ON
        }
        if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE.equals(state))
        {
            amanager.setRingerMode(0);  //Ringer Silent
        }
        if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK.equals(state))
        {
            amanager.setRingerMode(0);  ////Ringer Silent
        }
    }
       };
```

Inside the onStartCommand method in my service:

```
      IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
      filter.addAction(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED);
      registerReceiver(CallReceiver, filter);
```

The service is running successfully and the receiver detects when there is an incoming call but the app crashes afterwards, any ideas why this is happening?
your help is appreciated!

EDIT:
I solved the issue, turns out I wrote the wrong action in the manifest, it doesn't crash after changing it.

BUT now the receiver only detects an incoming call but doesn't detect when the call is answered or over, it did detect it a couple of times but most of the times it doesn't, the ringer is still on after the call is over!
any ideas?

Comment: Look at the crash in logcat and post the stacktrace and error message

Comment: I fixed the crash but now the receiver doesn't detect the end of the call and the phone stays in the normal ringer mode after the call is over..

Comment: How are you starting/stopping your service? What do you return from `onStartCommand()`? Can you tell if your service is still running when the call completes?

Comment: I'm starting the service from the main activity, onCreate() method, by starting the service through an intent:
        Intent service = new Intent(this, CallDetectService.class);
        startService(service); 

I'm returning this from onStartCommand():
    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;

I'm not sure if the service is still running, it doesn't show any sign of being terminated after the fix I made though.

Comment: Try returning "START_STICKY" from `onStartCommand()`. This should keep your service running. I'm guessing that your service is just being killed off during the phone call.

Comment: did that, still having the same problem, I added this to the onDestroy() method inside the service to detect if it's being killed:

Toast.makeText(this,"ServiceTerminated..",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
and the toast is not being shown at any point, which means the service is still running right?

Comment: Not necessarily. Android can just kill off the process without calling `onDestroy()`

Comment: If you look at the documentation for `ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED`, there are only 3 states defined: IDLE, RINGING and OFFHOOK. So it doesn't look like you will get any state change broadcast until the call is completed and it goes back to IDLE. Add debug logging to your `onReceive()` and check logcat to see if it gets called. Don't use `Toast` for this, that is not reliable from a broadcast receiver.

Comment: Are you unregistering your receiver too early?

Comment: I think the service is running without problems, I'm not unregistering the receiver at all, since I need it to detect the change during all the time when the service is alive.
Now the receiver is detecting the call and the end of call correctly for the first time, but when I try a new call it changes the ringer mode to Ring then to silent for a fraction of a second when the call is over and then goes back to normal ringer mode!

Comment: The likely you have some other problem in your code. Add more debug logging and good luck!

Comment: Thanks man, I'll answer here if I found a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured a way out!
I added a delay of one second before setting the ringer mode to silent, I have no idea how this solution worked, but it did!

```
private final BroadcastReceiver CallReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        AudioManager amanager=(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        amanager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

        if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE.equals(state))
        {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            amanager.setRingerMode(0);  //Ringer Silent
        }
        if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK.equals(state))
        {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            amanager.setRingerMode(0);  ////Ringer Silent
        }
        if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(state))
        {
            amanager.setRingerMode(2);  //Ringer ON
        }
    }
       };
```